# Replacing Clavier.lireDouble

Tags: java

Hello to all and best wishes for 2014.

My question is ... In the following program is it possible to replace the `ht = Clavier.lireDouble ()` to simplify the package because every time I implement this command I have to create a class "Clavier.java "this increased the source code ?

Thank you for your answers

best regards

---

> **NOTE FROM EDITOR**
>
> Clavier is the French translation of keyboard. The Clavier class seems
>   to be used for educational purpose. The question asked here could be
>   "How can my java program read a value from the keyboard input?"

---

Billing program for lectuire a price exclusive of tax and VAT calculation and VAT and price discounts based on cost

r0%

1000 <= r1%

2000 <= r3%

r5%> = $ 5000 */

/*Program (In french)*/

```
public class Tva
{
  public static void  main (String[]args)
  {    
   double ht;
   double  ttc, net, tauxr, remise;
   double taux_tva = 21.6;

   System.out.print ("donnez le prix hors taxe :");
   ht = Clavier.lireDouble();  /*Replace this command*/

   ttc = ht * (1. + taux_tva/100);
   if (ttc < 1000.)                    tauxr =  0;
       else if (ttc < 2000)            tauxr =  1.;
            else if (ttc < 5000)       tauxr =  3.;
               else                    tauxr  = 5.;

   remise = ttc * tauxr / 1000;
   net = ttc - remise;
   System.out.println ("Prix Ttc : "+ ttc);
   System.out.println ("Remise : "+ remise);
   System.out.println ("Net à payer : "+ net);

   }
}
```

Comment: Replace it with what?

Comment: I do not wish to print a page dedicated to Clavier.java class by removing the command line Clavier.lireDouble. I tried with System.out.println but in this case the Jvm asks me to initialize ht 0 which is not suitable for the application program ...

Comment: Your question makes no sense, and your comment still makes no sense. I understand you want to remove the reference to Clavier - but what does Clavier.lireDouble do? What is it? Without knowing what it does how are we supposed to suggest a replacement?

Comment: It is also possible that he does not exist other solution is what I want to be sure :-)

Comment: Clavier.lireDouble seems to be an order of old Java versions, I do not understand is why I ask if anyone can answer ...

Comment: Replace it with `Scanner` and its `nextDouble()` method.

Comment: It appears that part of the java.io package and class Clavier.java

Comment: thank you Marko I test your suggestion :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class for that purpose.

You code to replace can become

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
ht = scan.nextDouble();
```

One remark : my mother tongue is also French but IMHO I think it is better to code in English because it is always possible that you will have to share/submit... your code to people who don't understand your mother tongue so it will make things more difficult. 
Ah I was about to forget it : because `Clavier` is a French word, you can be sure it never existed in Java or standard JDK.

Comment: The `Clavier` class is generally provided by some University in order to learn Java development. That's unfortunately a bad practice :(

Comment: I can understand it in the very very beginning of programming learning but it is a poisened chalice.

Comment: @Célia-ViolaineBouchard You're welcome! Please mark this anwser as accepted so people having the same question can find this answer more easily.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effective responses ... my demand is met, the program works fine now :-)   Best regards

Comment: Following your edit @C.Champagne, I voted to reopen the question.